# MongoDB Doctrine ODM change the collection name for a document at run time

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm, odm

I have to create collection for users per each day they register so if I have 5 users and 2 register on 2013-03-02 and 3 have register on 2013-03-03 I will have 2 collections

The user is declare in a YML file with no collection

In the project I do an import via CLI something like this

```
      foreach($arUsers as $key=>$arUser)
  {

    $collection_name = "day_".$arUser['date'];


    $user = new User();

    /* Change the collection name to be dynamic  */
    $OdmMetaData = MeltApplication::getDocumentManager()->getClassMetaData( get_class($user) );
    $OdmMetaData->setCollection($collection_name);

    $user->setUserId($arUser['user_id']);
    $user->setEmail($arUser['email']);
    ....

    $this->getDocumentManager()->persist($user);
    $this->getDocumentManager()->flush();
  }
```

Problem is that when I look in the mongoDB I see only one collection with name day_2013-03-03" which is the last date , if I set the MeltApplication::getDocumentManager()->flush(); after the foreach end statement which I should it save all in the first collection 03-02 .

Are there any options to do this , to save them separate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = $odm->getClassMetadata('NameEntity');
$data->setCollection($collectionName);
```

This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution was to reinitialized the documentManager

Comment: How did you do it?